# Как в elasticsearch добавить свой словарь hunspell?

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearch версии 8.7.1
По документации словари надо располагать в /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/hunspell/, но такой папки у меня нету на сервере. Создаю вручную, заливаю туда файлы, перезагружаю сервис и все равно ничего не появляется

Как добавить свой словарь?

[Папка присутствует но анализатор говорит что такого словаря нет](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqQex.png)

`

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
        "reason": "failed to load hunspell dictionary for locale: ru_RU"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_state_exception",
    "reason": "failed to load hunspell dictionary for locale: ru_RU",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "exception",
      "reason": "Could not find hunspell dictionary [ru_RU]"
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

`